# npm global install path got totally screwed up

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm

I tried dealing with the Node.js permission issue for installing new modules and in the process it got totally screwed up so when I install something globally, it just doesn't have a terminal function.
For instance, the default path used to be /usr/local/lib/node_modules, but right now whenever I install something with npm -g, it installs it in my OSX home folder (!!) and it is not accessible globally.
I tried removing everything, reinstalling Node.js, nothing helps.
It all happened after following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Using these lines:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Please help.. I've been at it for hours now :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you verify the configuration of npm?

Run the following command

```
npm config ls -l
```

To check the configuration of npm (both with and without sudo).

You may try to uninstall Node.js, remove the npm configuration files (npmrc) if any, or any other npm folder left, and install again.

Changing the permission of a system folder as */usr/local/lib/node_modules* is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are several problems.

> right now whenever I install something with npm -g, it installs it in my OSX home folder (!!) and it is not accessible globally.

npm maintains a cache in ~/.npm in your home directory.  This is not an installation location, just a cache of downloaded packages and other data.  If this is causing you grief, you can get rid of it temporarily with

`npm cache clean`

`npm` will recreate and repopulate the cache as it runs.

One way to rescue the situation is to download and run this script < https://github.com/DomT4/scripts/blob/master/OSX_Node_Removal/terminatenode.sh > which will remove node completely.  You can then install with the installer < http://nodejs.org/download/ > or homebrew, whichever you prefer.

One last point, though, is that when you install a package globally, you cannot `require` it: you get new commands.  For example:

`$ jshint
    -bash: jshint: command not found
    $ npm install -g jshint
    $ jshint 
    $`

Now I have the `jshint` command installed and can use it to analyze source files; but I cannot `require('jshint')` from any code, because that doesn't look in the global `node_modules` directory.  This is intentional; the goal is to make each package declare its dependencies completely, so it is easier to move a package from one host to another without having to figure out what undocumented dependencies need to be installed on the target system.