# Why npm modules installed globally can't be listed?

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm

I'm running:

```
npm ls -g
```

And it doesn`t show anything.

I`m pretty sure I have modules installed. If I run:

```
ls -1 usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

The result is:

```
express
forever
fstream
fstream-ignore
generator-keystone
http-server
keystone
node-debug
node-gyp
node-inspector
npm
yo
```

The command perfectly works for locally installed modules.

Adding the results of `npm config ls -l` that maybe could help more.

```
; cli configs
long = true
user-agent = "npm/3.3.12 node/v4.1.2 darwin x64"

; default values
access = null
also = null
always-auth = false
bin-links = true
browser = null
ca = null
cache = "/Users/ash/.npm"
cache-lock-retries = 10
cache-lock-stale = 60000
cache-lock-wait = 10000
cache-max = null
cache-min = 10
cafile = undefined
cert = null
color = true
depth = null
description = true
dev = false
dry-run = false
editor = "vi"
engine-strict = false
fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
force = false
git = "git"
git-tag-version = true
global = false
globalconfig = "/usr/local/etc/npmrc"
globalignorefile = "/usr/local/etc/npmignore"
group = 20
heading = "npm"
https-proxy = null
if-present = false
ignore-scripts = false
init-author-email = ""
init-author-name = ""
init-author-url = ""
init-license = "ISC"
init-module = "/Users/ash/.npm-init.js"
init-version = "1.0.0"
json = false
key = null
link = false
local-address = undefined
loglevel = "warn"
; long = false (overridden)
message = "%s"
node-version = "4.1.2"
npat = false
onload-script = null
only = null
optional = true
parseable = false
prefix = "/usr/local"
production = false
progress = true
proprietary-attribs = true
proxy = null
rebuild-bundle = true
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
rollback = true
save = false
save-bundle = false
save-dev = false
save-exact = false
save-optional = false
save-prefix = "^"
scope = ""
searchexclude = null
searchopts = ""
searchsort = "name"
shell = "/bin/bash"
shrinkwrap = true
sign-git-tag = false
strict-ssl = true
tag = "latest"
tag-version-prefix = "v"
tmp = "/var/folders/3r/9ljlgw6j7m53hwxm_3c3gdkw000106/T"
umask = 18
unicode = true
unsafe-perm = true
usage = false
user = 501
; user-agent = "npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}" (overridden)
userconfig = "/Users/ash/.npmrc"
version = false
versions = false
viewer = "man"
```

Comment: If you install a package with the `-g` flag, does it land in your `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` directory?  Or does it get installed elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. I just installed socket.io to try figure out and it's been placed in that folder.

Comment: `npm ls -g` should work fine. It looks like some configuration of environmental problem.

Comment: I read somewhere that may be some wrong indication in `prefix = "/usr/local"` that should be set to usr/local/lib/node_modules/, but I can't locate the file where this is specified. It is supposed to be a .npmrc file.

Comment: Ok. No need to locate the file because it's possible to change prefix with: `npm config set prefix /usr/local/ -g` anyway, but nothing really changes and still no modules displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue in a brutal way, but at the end of the answer you will find suggestions to be more gentle with your machine.

I actually reinstalled node. Before doing this I deleted everything of the previous installation as suggested in some other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676864/npm-global-install-path-got-totally-screwed-up).

[Here](https://github.com/DomT4/scripts/blob/master/OSX_Node_Removal/terminatenode.sh) is the direct link to the script suggested in the previous post.

For the rest you should already know how to install Node.

Lesson learned: Use always nvm and think a couple of times before installing/uninstalling with -g option.

Now `npm ls -g --depth=0` works as a charm:

```
/usr/local/lib
├── generator-keystone@0.3.9
├── npm@2.14.7
└── yo@1.5.0
```

I was then curios about the changing of the config file.

I've run again: `npm config ls -l`

It starts similar:

```
; cli configs
long = true
user-agent = "npm/2.14.7 node/v4.2.2 darwin x64"
```

Then come these new lines that were missing:

```
; globalconfig /usr/local/etc/npmrc
prefix = "/usr/local"
```

And then remains the same:

```
; default values
access = null
[..]
```

So, a more fit answer would be as it follows.

I haven't tested it in the end, but if you installed everything by default theres a file npmrc in /usr/local/etc. To make it point to the right location you should run:

```
npm config set globalconfig /etc/npmrc
```

For details on [globalconfig](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#globalconfig)

Hope that's all folks.